# What is the preferred way of including media queries in HTML?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I was wondering what is the preferred way of including CSS stylesheets in your HTML with a responsive web design in mind. As far as I know there are two different ways of doing so - either using one CSS file with many media queries in it, or having multiple separate CSS files, calling them based on the `media` attribute of the `<link>` tag.

For example, either (in the CSS file):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    ...
    ...
}
```

or (in the HTML file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:768px)" href="style768.css" />
```

In what cases would you use one file instead of multiple files, and vice versa? I guess there isn't one "proper" way of doing it, but what are some pros and cons of either way?

Comment: I prefer to use one stylesheet because I would  rather the browser request 1 resource instead of many, especially when it's unnecessary to have multiple. Also, you could even import other sheets from within the main CSS.

Comment: So I ask about the pros and cons of something I couldn't find much information about on the internet, and you deem it opinion based. Cool... I'll use Quora next time ffs

Comment: It looks like multiple people flagged it as opinion, but even then, no need to get upset about it. This site is geared for questions and answers, not questions and discussions. And to be honest, because it's being marked as opinion and because you can't find much on it, might mean there really isn't a definitive answer to what you're asking. From experience, I've never seen someone have separate stylesheets for media queries, they also contain them in their master sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is kind of an opinion question. A huge pro of using just one file is that it's just 1 network request. But with splitting up the media queries into multiple files and using the media attribute when linking, the browser agent can determine which file to load instead of loading all of them. In the former case, there is only 1 request, but more code loaded, and in the latter case, there is less code loaded, but 2 requests. You could be more granular about when to use which, based on how much media specific styles you want to include, but personally I like to just bundle into one file, especially when using a workflow with tools like Webpack or Gulp.